# EVGA GTX 1080 Ti Fan Controls Malfunctioning (Precision X1)

Tags: graphics-card, fan, computer-building

I was looking for some help regarding my GTX 1080 Ti's software fan controls. Using EVGA Precision X1, I normally only get 1 or 2 fan sliders. I have the EVGA GTX 1080 Ti FTW3, three fan model.

First, I made sure all cables were plugged in fully, and I am 99% sure all the cables are functioning properly and plugged in properly, and that the power supply is working properly. After checking all of those, I tried the following steps:

1. Shutdown your pc.
2. Unplug PSU from wall.
3. Press & hold tower power on button for 30 seconds.
4. Plug PSU back into wall.
5. Start pc.
6. Start Precision X1.

This works until I restart or turn off my PC. On a related note, sometimes while playing games my PC just randomly restarts without a warning, it just shuts down without a warning, then boots back up. Reliability monitor says: "The previous system shutdown at 2:59:39 PM on ‎11/‎27/‎2022 was unexpected."
Thanks for the help!

My Rig:

- AMD Ryzen 7 5700X 8-Core
- Cooler Master A71C
- MSI B450 TOMAHAWK MAX II
- XPG SPECTRIX D60G 16 GB RAM
- EVGA GeForce GTX 1080 Ti FTW3
- Corsair 5000D Case
- EVGA SuperNOVA 750 GA
- Inland Professional 240GB SSD

Comment: Is the fan defective (hardware issue)?  Lack of fan cooling could shut down the machine.

Comment: I don't think so, because sometimes I can control all of the fans and they all work perfectly fine.

Comment: Try testing memory (bad memory causes this) and for Root Kit viruses (TDSS Killer by Kaspersky)

Comment: Here's the result: https://imgur.com/OaAvrMj

Comment: It may be a memory then, or more serious damage to the operating system.

Comment: I also scanned my PC with malwarebytes recently and it found no viruses

Comment: You may need to reinstall the operating system. Back up first

Comment: I ran "sfc /scannow" and it found 
`Corrupt file CWindowsSystem32driversBthA2dp.sys`
`Corrupt file CWindowsSystem32driversBthHfEnum.sys`
`Corrupt file CWindowsSystem32driversbthmodem.sys`
(Repaired them all) Which all seem to be bluetooth drivers.

Comment: Has this fixed your computer fan? Not clear

Comment: No, I thought it did but after a PC crash, and me checking the fan speeds in EVGA Precision X1, which is currently showing only one fan, it did not fix it. I think this could be a memory issue, but I don't know, I will do some more testing and benchmarking tomorrow. So far, the PC crashes when playing fortnite, but I haven't experienced crashes in any other games, I'm assuming it is my PC but it could also be a Epic Games issue.

Comment: Now, most games crash, including forza horizon 5, Trackmainia, and some others. The difference is that they do not turn off my PC, they just simply close.

Comment: I ran memtest86 twice, and everything passed without any errors both times.